# Update a column based on value of another column

Tags: split, expression, power-automate

I want a Power Automate flow to update a column (Pickable) based on the value of another column (Location). The logic is that if the character after the second period in the Location column is a 3, the Pickable location value should be "No." Otherwise it should be "Yes." Here's my set up.

- List Rows (Dataverse table)
- Apply to Each (output from List Rows)

  - Update a Row (same table as List Rows / row ID is the standard Dataverse ID column)

This is the expression I **want** to use in the Update a Row action for the Pickable column, but it doesn't work:

`if(split(item()?['Location'], '.')[2]='3','No','Yes')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `equals` expression, you can't just use the `=` sign within the PowerAutomate expression context.

This is untested but adapt this as need be ...

```
if(equals(split(string(item()?['Location']), '.')[2], '3'),'No','Yes')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error. I can confirm that all rows in the table do not have null values. "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Update_a_row' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'split' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'."

Comment: I updated my answer to include the `string` expression but not sure that will help.  This is going away from your original question a little.  Can you confirm what the contents of the `Location` property looks like?  A screenshot would help.

Comment: It could be the user_friendly name is Location, but once you start writing expressions, the real name is something like cr123_location, this can be different from your name. (Assuming you use a dataverse column).